# SQL Server 2017 Server Name , Aliases, and Client Protocols

Tags: sql-server-2017, server-name

A new SQL Server 2017 (CU31) was just brought up at our company. It is hosted on a Windows Server 2019 Datacenter on a VM.

For the most part, everything is working fine but there is a weird latency issue in one part of our ERP system that needs to be resolved.

When I `select * from sys.servers` I see the following name (example):  MySQLServer-NEW

We cannot connect to `MySQLServer-NEW` via SSMS, ODBC, or remote desktop. Only by the "aliases" such as `MySQlServerOld` or `MySQLServer`.

Per our Sys Admin `MySQlServerOld` and `MySQLServer` are the only valid host names on the VM. Was told that "SQL Server added this" and it won't work with Active Directory or Kerberos authentication.

I'm seeing queries in our monitoring tool that select from the new server name noted in `sys.servers` though and these are successful.

Example

```
Select * 
From [MySQLServer-NEW].[databaseName].dbo.TableName
```

Does something need to be renamed in SQL Server? I do not understand how most things are working with a name that isn't really available

Our ERP system requires named pipes and the doc indicates that it should be set first before TCP/IP.

When looking at SQL Server Config Protocols I see SQL Native Client 11 (thought there would be something newer) although Named Pipes is enabled here.

Named Pipes is disabled under `MSSQLServer` which is what the SQL Server service runs as.

[SQL Server configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nbFV.png)

My searches didn't find anything that seemed related.  Obviously on my own here and don't know what I'm looking at...

Comment: So you mention MySQLServer but then also say SQL Server Config Protocols .. are you trying to connect to a SQL or a MySQL server ?  Also the server is a vm image ?  And it updates and retains data on reboots?  Because maybe that is the problem perhaps?

Comment: Sql server 2017 is what we connect to.  I used the name "MySqlServer-NEW" in place of the name of our production sql server.  No MySQL involved.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: thanks for the update, it will help someone fix it, alas I do MySQL myself.

Comment: Some clarification:

Comment: Some clarification...  This is Microsoft SQL Server 2017.  Have been doing some further reading.  The instance name (@@ServerName) returns the name of the host server (MySqlServer-NEW). So, this name would have been picked up during sql server install.   We are not to connect to the server using this name.  Only to use MySqlServerOld or MySQLServer which I'm told are aliases in DNS.  When I look at SERVERPROPERTY('servername')  it returns MySqlServerOld.  It sounds like perhaps we need to drop MySqlServer-NEW and add MySqlServerOld.  If anyone can clarify that would be great.